# VF page: buttons and fields outside of <form> tag in DOM Explorer

Tags: visualforce

For some of the user Profiles, my VF page is not able to submit using `apex:CommandButton`s.  When clicked, nothing happens - there are no errors on the JS console and no debug files created for the user.  I traced the issue down to output HTML and it appears that the buttons (and fields) are not contained within the main `form` tag.  This is confusing since my VF page only has 1 open and 1 close `form` tag and all elements are contained within the form.

Users in Production are experiencing this issue fully but I can only replicate the issue in test environments some of the time.  System Admin Profile users do not have this problem at all.

Is this a known issue with a known work-around?  Has anyone seen something like this before?

Unfortunately, I cannot include all of the code and output HTML due to client restrictions but I can try to include snippets of code/HTML as needed.

Note: I was able to get the buttons working by creating `apex:actionFunction`s for each button that does nothing more than call the Apex method that the button normally calls.  Of course, this does not help with saving any updates on the page.

Note 2: This problem is occurring on 2 page - the View and Edit pages which share the same Controller.

I have to assume that this is an actual Salesforce bug and I will likely end up sending them a ticket but I expect this is a quicker way of getting a fix/work-around and time is not on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that including the Chatter Feed tag caused the HTML to be malformed by the browser.  If the page was loaded with the feed open then the HTML would malform and the main form was shut too early.  If the page was loaded with the Chatter Feed hidden then it would work.

My fix was to remove the tag completely.  I hope this helps someone down the line.